how to add multiple interfaces in `/etc/hosts.allow` file?
SSH is listening on all the available 10 Ethernet interfaces in my system. I have tested using nc 160.49.198.97 22 command in Linux. To allow only particular interface and block others, i have created hosts.deny and hosts.allow files in `/etc/ folder.
Below is hosts.deny file
sshd: ALL
Below is hosts.allow file
sshd: 160.49.198.97
Now along with 160.49.198.97, I need to add 160.49.198.185 and 160.49.198.199 also in hosts.allow file. How to add them? Should i separate IP's by comma? or by space ??

Look at the examples on the man page ("10 Ethernet interfaces" !)

@symcbean, Can you pls let me know which man page exactly?

open a terminal. Type man hosts.allow. Read the output. When you're finished with your network config, learn how to use man and info; these have the definitive and up to date documentation for what is on your host (the internet is full of content promoted on the basis of its SEO rather than its accuracy / relevance / timeliness).

The relevant man page is also available under the name "hosts_access", so in a terminal window man hosts_access should show you the man page.
